# Puppeteer change proxy of already opened browser page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Once I open a puppeteer browser page and redirect to a specific site. If the proxy used for the browser is banned, I want to be able to switch it without closing or restarting the browser. refreshing the browser would be the best option. However, I have not yet been able to figure out how to do it. I've tried making variables out of '--proxy-server=xxxx' and switching that variable whenever proxy is banned, but that didnt work out. I've tried many other things too but have yet been able to figure it out. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

```
    var proxies = get_proxy() // get proxy
    var useragent = randomUseragent.getRandom()
    
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
      headless: false,
      args: [
      `--proxy-server=${proxies.address}:${proxies.port}`,
      `--user-agent="${useragent}"`,
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-infobars',
      '--window-position=0,0',
      '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
      '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list'
      ]
    })

    let page = await browser.newPage()
```

Example of how i want it to be:

```
const proxy_banned = await check_proxy_ban()

If(proxy_banned){
 - Switch puppeteer browser proxy
 - refresh
 - return function
} else{
 - return function
}
```